# Control+Shift + Mouse Wheel with xbindkeys shortcuts propagate

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gnome, xbindkeys

My `.xbindkeysrc` file includes:

```
"amixer sset -q 'Master' 10%+"
  control + shift + b:4

"amixer sset -q 'Master' 10%-"
  control + shift + b:5
```

Which allows me to control sound volume with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **Mouse Wheel**.
This worked perfectly fine until a recent upgrade.

Currently this works, but it also passes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Wheel** to the underlying window - which usually results in zoom in/out (for example in the browser or in terminator).

**How can I change the volume without zooming? :-)**

I am using arch linux, and gnome with xorg.

- gnome 41.3
- X.Org X Server 21.1.3

Update: the same happens also when using [sxhkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sxhkd).

(2022-02, Updated versions, problem persists)

Comment: Was it a full system upgrade or just  the upgrade to xbindkeys 1.8.6-1?

Comment: full system upgrade.

Comment: Does not seem to be an xbindkeys problem. I can even reproduce this with [sxkhd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sxhkd)!

Comment: Having the same problems on elementaryOS

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1335654

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation but with xdotool

```
"xdotool key XF86AudioPlay"
    shift + b:4
```

According to [xbindkeys#Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Troubleshooting) article on archlinux wiki, I updated it to include --clearmodifiers, which worked for me.

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioPlay"
    shift + b:4
```

It also mentions using `+ release` at the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks - Since I am not using `xdotool`, this does not relate or solve the problem.